# How do I extract just the time from a datetimepicker component in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker component in a Delphi form and I would like to just get the Time. When i look at the date in debug mode I see `42544.621701`, and I would like just to get  `0.621701` without the date value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`Frac()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Frac) function:

```
var
  Time: TTime;
...
  Time := Frac(DateTimePicker1.DateTime);
```

Or, you can use the [`System.DateUtils.TimeOf()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.DateUtils.TimeOf) function, which is merely an inlined wrapper around `Frac()` with a more descriptive name:

```
uses
  ..., DateUtils;

var
  Time: TTime;
...
  Time := TimeOf(DateTimePicker1.DateTime);
```

Comment: _System.DateUtils_ has a function `TimeOf`, which is merely an inlined wrapper around `Frac`, but with a more descriptive name.

Comment: With property `kind = dtkTime`, use the `Time` property to get the time.

Comment: @LURD: in my experience, the `Time` property usually includes a date value, and the `Date` property usually includes a `Time` value. This is because they are both backed by the `DateTime` property, but their getters try to truncate the value and don't always. So I always use `DateOf()` and `TimeOf()` to manually strip off unwanted data, just in case.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yepp I can confirm that. Seems to be a long standing bug.

Comment: It's more than a wrapper with a descriptive name. It provides insulation against implementation detail.

Answer (score 6):

The question is not actually about a date time picker. The control returns you a date time value. You are looking for a way to extract just the time portion. Do that with the [`TimeOf`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.TimeOf) function from the `System.DateUtils` unit.

```
 MyTime := TimeOf(MyDateTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

EditHoo.Text:=timetostr(DateTimePicker2.Time);

Comment: Your answer is confusing and lacks any description. The OP wants to obtain the numeric time value (fractional part of the datetime value), not a string containing only the time value (which is a simpler problem that the OP no doubt already knows how to solve). So a few years ago, your A would only have displayed a misunderstanding of the OP. However, if I am not mistaken, the `Time` property has recently been changed to include the necessary `TimeOf` (~`Frac`) part, so your A actually contains the solution (`DateTimePicker2.Time`), but you hide it behind `TimeToStr`, making it look irrelevant.